# Having trouble listing all values of JSON using map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Json data something like this

```
{
 A: {name: 'a', date: 'x'}
B: {name: 'b', date: 'x'}
C: {name: 'c', date: 'x'}
D: {name: 'd', date: 'x'}

}
```

I am trying to list all the name. However, i get an error

> .data.map is not a function

My code looks something like this:

```
 {data.map((item) => {
    return(
      <div>
     {item.name}
    </div> )
 })}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method, it does not exist on objects.

Comment: If you don't need the object keys, just use object.values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Object.values(data).map( // the rest
```

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will give you an array of a given object's own enumerable property values.

Comment: Thank you! it works!

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an object not an array and .Map() is an Array method.

You can do something similar with an object this way

```
 {data && Object.values(data).map((propVal) => {
    return(
      <div>
     {propVal}
    </div> )
 })}
```

You can also use Object.entries() each entry is an array with two elements. entry[0] is the key while entry[1] is the value.
This way you can also add a check for the prop name.

```
 {data && Object.entries(data).map((entry) => {
            if(entry[0] === 'name') {
               return(
                  <div>
                 {propVal}
                </div> )
             })}    
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: object.entries does not work like this

Comment: Object.values() works, but he use only the name attribute.

Comment: I added object entries as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You've to convert your object values to array.

```
{data && Object.values(data).map((item) => {
    return(
      <div>
     {item.name}
    </div> )
 })}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, my bad. I didn't see that the data was an object.

Comment: object.entries gives an array of arrays

Comment: Yes, its object.values which will give array.